# Dont get fields from a related table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a Table objekt_history

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\ObjektHistory" table="objekt_history"    repository-class="MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Repository\ObjektHistoryRepository">
 <indexes>
  <index name="id_objekt_objektnummer_fk1_idx" columns="objektnummer"/>
  <index name="id_objekt_subunternehmer_fk2_idx" columns="id_subunternehmer"/>
</indexes>
<id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
<field name="datum" type="datetime" column="datum" nullable="false"/>
<field name="typ" type="boolean" column="typ" nullable="false"/>
<field name="outbox" type="boolean" column="outbox" nullable="false"/>
<many-to-one field="objektnummer" target-entity="Objekt">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="objektnummer" referenced-column-name="objektnummer"/>
    <join-column name="id_subunternehmer" referenced-column-name="id_subunternehmer"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
</entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

The Objekt Table is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
<entity name="MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt" table="objekt" repository-class="MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Repository\ObjektRepository">
<indexes>
  <index name="id_subunternehmer_fk1_idx" columns="id_subunternehmer"/>
  <index name="id_mbs_filiale_fk2_idx" columns="id_mbs_filiale"/>
</indexes>
<id name="objektnummer" type="integer" column="objektnummer"/>
<id name="idSubunternehmer" association-key="true"/>
<field name="anschrift1" type="string" column="anschrift1" length="45" nullable="true"/>
<field name="anschrift2" type="string" column="anschrift2" length="45" nullable="false"/>
<field name="strasse" type="string" column="strasse" length="45" nullable="false"/>
<field name="plz" type="string" column="plz" length="45" nullable="false"/>
<field name="ort" type="string" column="ort" length="45" nullable="false"/>
<field name="land" type="string" column="land" length="45" nullable="false"/>
<field name="telefon1" type="string" column="telefon1" length="45" nullable="true"/>
<field name="telefon2" type="string" column="telefon2" length="45" nullable="true"/>
<field name="projektstatus" type="boolean" column="projektstatus" nullable="false"/>
<field name="projektstatusvornichtbeauftragt" type="boolean" column="projektstatusvornichtbeauftragt" nullable="false"/>
<field name="erstellungsdatum" type="datetime" column="erstellungsdatum" nullable="true"/>
<field name="startdatum" type="date" column="startdatum" nullable="true"/>
<field name="endedatum" type="date" column="endedatum" nullable="true"/>
<field name="rechnungsnummer" type="string" column="rechnungsnummer" length="45" nullable="true"/>
<field name="rechnungsdatum" type="date" column="rechnungsdatum" nullable="true"/>
<field name="lohnfahrtkosten" type="float" column="lohnfahrtkosten" precision="10" scale="2" nullable="true"/>
<field name="mwst" type="float" column="mwst" precision="10" scale="2" nullable="true"/>
<field name="werktage" type="integer" column="werktage" nullable="false"/>
<field name="portalnutzungsgebuehr" type="float" column="portalnutzungsgebuehr" precision="10" scale="2" nullable="true"/>
<field name="gesperrt" type="boolean" column="gesperrt" nullable="false"/>
<field name="fertigstellungsdatum" type="date" column="fertigstellungsdatum" nullable="true"/>
<field name="rechnungfreigegeben" type="date" column="rechnungfreigegeben" nullable="true"/>
<field name="korrektur" type="boolean" column="korrektur" nullable="false"/>
<field name="archiviert" type="boolean" column="archiviert" nullable="false"/>
<one-to-one field="idSubunternehmer" target-entity="Subunternehmer">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="id_subunternehmer" referenced-column-name="subunternehmernummer"/>
  </join-columns>
</one-to-one>
<many-to-one field="idMbsFiliale" target-entity="MbsFiliale">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="id_mbs_filiale" referenced-column-name="filialnummer"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
</entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

This is my Entity ObjektHistory:

```
namespace MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ObjektHistory
 */
class ObjektHistory
{
  /**
   * @var \DateTime
   */
  private $datum;

  /**
   * @var boolean
   */
  private $typ;

  /**
   * @var boolean
   */
  private $outbox;

  /**
   * @var integer $uid
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var \MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt
   */
  private $idSubunternehmer;

  /**
   * @var \MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt
   */
  private $objektnummer;


  /**
   * Set datum
   *
   * @param \DateTime $datum
   * @return ObjektHistory
   */
  public function setDatum($datum)
  {
     $this->datum = $datum;

     return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Get datum
   *
   * @return \DateTime 
   */
  public function getDatum()
  {
     return $this->datum;
  }

 /**
  * Set typ
  *
  * @param boolean $typ
  * @return ObjektHistory
  */
 public function setTyp($typ)
 {
    $this->typ = $typ;

    return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Get typ
  *
  * @return boolean 
  */
 public function getTyp()
 {
    return $this->typ;
 }

 /**
  * Set outbox
  *
  * @param boolean $outbox
  * @return ObjektHistory
  */
 public function setOutbox($outbox)
 {
    $this->outbox = $outbox;

    return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Get outbox
  *
  * @return boolean 
  */
 public function getOutbox()
 {
    return $this->outbox;
 }

 /**
  * Get id
  *
  * @return integer 
  */
 public function getId()
 {
    return $this->id;
 }

 /**
  * Set idSubunternehmer
  *
  * @param \MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt $idSubunternehmer
  * @return ObjektHistory
  */
 public function setIdSubunternehmer(\MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt $idSubunternehmer = null)
 {
    $this->idSubunternehmer = $idSubunternehmer;

    return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Get idSubunternehmer
  *
  * @return \MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt 
  */
 public function getIdSubunternehmer()
 {
    return $this->idSubunternehmer;
 }

 /**
  * Set objektnummer
  *
  * @param \MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt $objektnummer
  * @return ObjektHistory
  */
 public function setObjektnummer(\MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt $objektnummer = null)
 {
    $this->objektnummer = $objektnummer;

    return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Get objektnummer
  *
  * @return \MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Objekt 
  */
 public function getObjektnummer()
 {
    return $this->objektnummer;
 }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
namespace MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use MBS\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\ObjektHistory;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $securityContext = $this->container->get( 'security.context' );
    if( $securityContext->isGranted( 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' ) )
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $objektHistoryRepo = $em->getRepository( 'MBSAllgemeinBundle:ObjektHistory' )
                                ->findBy(array("typ" =>2) , array('datum' => 'DESC'));

        return $this->render(
            'MBSAllgemeinBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
            array(
                "History" => $objektHistoryRepo
            )
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }
}
}
```

When i try to search in the Respository with

->findBy(array("objektnummer" =>1234567) , array('datum' => 'DESC'));

i got the error

```
A single-valued association path expression to an entity with a composite primary key is not supported. Explicitly name the components of the composite primary key in the query.
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it required to define indexes for `objektnummer` ? I think this issue is due to the relation structure between entities

Comment: Are you trying to relate two fields from `objekt` to two fields in `objektHistory`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the relation ManyToOne in your **objektHistory** entity should be defined like this:

```
<many-to-one field="objektnummer" target-entity="Objekt" join-column="objektnummer">
   <join-column name="id_subunternehmer" referenced-column-name="objektnummer" />
</many-to-one>
```

And you do not need to define those indexes in your entities